# Display frame from VNC/RFB into an OpenGL application

Tags: c++, opengl, undefined-reference, vnc

I would like to be able to display remote client in a simple OpenGL application. "Simple" means only display the client such as a texture.

I started to look the VNC protocol but due to their popularity I only have few documentation related to VNCViewer. About RFB the only documentation is: http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf which is cool to understand the protocol but not enough to use it in a C++ OpenGL application. Then I found: http://libvnc.github.io/

I tried to compile the example (downloaded from github). So I added into my qtproject all rfb headers files run cmake on some of them. Then I built it but got the error:

```
undefined reference to `rfbMakeXCursor' and many others related to rfbXxxxx
```

*rfb.h* contains declarations to those "undefined" errors.
I don't understand what did I do wrong. Has anybody already made it work?

I'm working on Windows 8.1 64bit using C++ qtCreator and MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

Headers are just ""able of contents" for the compiler to know, which functions can be called. You need to actually *link* to the library. The odds are, that since you've got it from GitHub you must first [build the library](http://libvnc.github.io/#building). The built library you then add to some "extras/lib" directory in your project, configure that directory as additional library directory and add the library to the linker flags.